# React Nested Routing issue on redirection

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Okay so basically i'm new to react and was trying to use react-router-dom in a react app, basically what i want is i want my root route "/" to get redirected to "/admin" and then "/admin" to "/admin/login" the url is being redirected from the code i have written but i see the page not found component instead.

My App component

```
function App() {
  return (
    // BrowserRouter
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/">
          <Redirect to="/admin" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
}
```

My Admin Component

```
export default function Admin(props: any) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin</h1>
      <Route path={`${props.match.path}`}>
        <Redirect to={`${props.match.path}/login`} exact={true} />
      </Route>

      <Route
        exact={true}
        path={`${props.match.path}/login`}
        component={Login}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Login Component

```
export default function Login(props: any) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **exact** from the admin path in APP component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    // BrowserRouter
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/admin" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
}
```

Add **exact** in the admin component

```
export default function Admin(props: any) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin</h1>         
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${props.match.path}`}>
          <Redirect to={`${props.match.path}/login`} exact={true} />
        </Route>    
        <Route
          exact={true}
          path={`${props.match.path}/login`}
          component={Login}
        />
        <Redirect to='404-page-path' />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, I would recommend you to use a linter, It's not necessary to write exact={true}, writing just exact is enough.

Edit as per the comment for 404 page.

Comment: In your solution if i go to the url /admin/login123 then it loads admin only but it should have gone to 404

Comment: I have updated the answer( admin component ) for 404 page, Import Switch from react-router-dom in the admin component

Comment: but i dont understand what did the switch do in the above case because we used exact to match exacly the path

Comment: Please go through the documentation on react-router, switch in this case works exactly like in any other language https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch, It matches the first route and if found  ignore others